# Custom user defined type for postgres not working with variable length text

Tags: c, postgresql, types, user-defined-types

## Overview

I'm trying to create a simple custom user defined type for postgres using C; however, whenever I query the table with the custom type, the data appears to be getting truncated (or there is an alignment issue). I believe I'm doing something wrong with handling the variable nature of the input.

### Here is my code:

```c
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(hierarchy_in);
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(hierarchy_out);

typedef struct Hierarchy
{
    int32 length;
    char path[FLEXIBLE_ARRAY_MEMBER];
} Hierarchy;


Datum
hierarchy_in(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    char *input_str = PG_GETARG_CSTRING(0);
    int32 input_len = strlen(input_str);
    Hierarchy *result;

    result = (Hierarchy *)palloc(VARHDRSZ + input_len);
    SET_VARSIZE(result, VARHDRSZ + input_len);
    strncpy(result->path, input_str, input_len);

    PG_RETURN_POINTER(result);
}

Datum
hierarchy_out(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    Hierarchy *input = (Hierarchy *)PG_GETARG_POINTER(0);
    char *result;
    int32 input_len = VARSIZE(input) - VARHDRSZ;

    result = pnstrdup(input->path, input_len);

    PG_RETURN_CSTRING(result);
}
```

### Here is my test case:

```sql
DROP TABLE TESTING;
DROP EXTENSION hierarchy CASCADE;

CREATE EXTENSION hierarchy;

CREATE TABLE TESTING (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    position hierarchy 
);

INSERT INTO TESTING (position) VALUES ('0123456789');
INSERT INTO TESTING (position) VALUES ('Hello World');

SELECT * FROM TESTING;
```

### Here is my output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is like the null-termination of your strings is missing.
While that would work, there would still be missing characters at the beginning.
Since [PostgreSQL data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/datatype.html) expects the first bytes to store the length of the variable-length data, the code would need to be:

```
typedef struct Hierarchy
{
    int32 length;
    char path[FLEXIBLE_ARRAY_MEMBER];
} Hierarchy;

Datum
hierarchy_in(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    char *input_str = PG_GETARG_CSTRING(0);
    int32 input_len = strlen(input_str);
    Hierarchy *result;

    result = (Hierarchy *)palloc(VARHDRSZ + sizeof(int32) + input_len); // Allocate space for length field
    SET_VARSIZE(result, VARHDRSZ + sizeof(int32) + input_len);
    result->length = input_len;
    memcpy(result->path, input_str, input_len); // Use memcpy without copying the null-terminator

    PG_RETURN_POINTER(result);
}

Datum
hierarchy_out(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    Hierarchy *input = (Hierarchy *)PG_GETARG_POINTER(0);
    char *result;
    int32 input_len = input->length;

    result = (char *)palloc(input_len + 1); // Allocate memory for the string plus the null-terminator
    memcpy(result, input->path, input_len); // Copy the data without the null-terminator
    result[input_len] = '\0'; // Manually add the null-terminator

    PG_RETURN_CSTRING(result);
}
```

From "[User-Defined Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xtypes.html)", the `VARSIZE` and `SET_VARSIZE` macros provided by PostgreSQL are used to handle the header portion.

The `hierarchy_in()` function already reads the input string without the null-terminator, stores the length of the string in the length field of the `Hierarchy` struct, and uses `memcpy` to copy the input string without the null-terminator to `result->path`.

However, the `hierarchy_out()` function creates a new null-terminated C-string from the extracted data and returns it as a C-string.
That should enable you to print said C-String, with all its expected characters.

Comment: It seems to have cleaned up the random bytes at the end; however, the first three characters of the string are still missing.

Comment: @ChristopherAliotta OK, I have rewritten the answer accordingly.

Comment: ERROR:  compressed pglz data is corrupt
LINE 1: INSERT INTO TESTING (position) VALUES ('0123456789');
                                               ^ 

SQL state: XX001
Character: 40

For the string based test, only the character 'H' is returned.

Comment: @ChristopherAliotta OK. Maybe using macros (`VARSIZE` and `SET_VARSIZE`) would help here. I have amended the code.

Comment: Several issues, first the error: flexible array member in a struct with no named members. So the Hierarchy struct provided in your example won't work. Second, if I revert the Hierarchy struct and use your updated code the application throws an error (it timesout) when I run the SELECT query.

Comment: @ChristopherAliotta I suspect the C99 standard does not allow structures with no named members other than a flexible array member.  I have edited the answer.